# How can I check if one layer contains another layer during animation?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, contains, layer

I need to check if one layer (red oval) contains another layer (white circle) during animation.

I've tried `CGRectContainsRect(layer1.presentationLayer()!.frame, layer2.presentationLayer()!.frame)`, but the frames always return 0,0...

My layer's declaration looks something like this:

```
        var target           = CAShapeLayer()
        target.path          = getBezierPath().CGPath
        target.fillColor     = nil
        target.strokeColor   = redTargetColor
        target.lineWidth     = lineWidth!
        target.lineCap       = kCALineCapRound
        target.strokeStart   = CGFloat(strokeStarts[index])
        target.strokeEnd     = CGFloat(strokeEnds[index])
```

Couldn't find any solution. What did I miss?

Comment: Just to be clear: you need to check if one layer frame is in another layer's frame? Or just check if one layer is the sublayer of another?

Comment: The first one. Tried to insert picture, but couldn't because of reputation. This is a game, where a white circle circulate by a path and when it is inside a red oval the user has to tap. I hope it is more clear now.